# Eldritch Smite using other slots?

Tags: eldritch-invocations

Can Invocations (like Eldritch Smite) use spell slots from the other classes’ spell slot table? They do say distinctly “Warlock spell slot”, but paladins at one point had the similar language.
Was this a way of limiting the Eldritch Smite?

Comment: Hi Mike, and welcome to the site. Check out our [tour] to see how we work here. Could you tell us which game and edition you're asking about? It sounds like D&D, but we can't make guesses, and I wouldn't be sure which edition of it you're referring to.

Comment: Are you referring to Dungeons and Dragons, ,5th edition, p. 56 of Xanathar's Guide to Everything, or to the Unearthed Arcana Eldritch Smite issued by WoTC on their web page?

Comment: @T.J.L. Please don't add a game tag when the asker has not clarified what edition they're using yet. [We do not guess the game people are using.](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6867/1204)